# Can I Use Some one Else Youtube Videos In My Flutter App

Tags: flutter, youtube-api

Please Tell me Can I Use Some one Else Youtube Videos In My Flutter App and Monatize it For Ads

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Ask for their permission. If they tell you not to, you legally ***cannot*** use his video if he denies you to do this. This is only if you are showing a video that is not connected to the YouTube site.

However, if you are not reuploading the video and you are just including his video's iframe in your application, it should be fine, as he is being credited.

Usually though, it's best to create your own content.